# pyinstaller FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, pyinstaller

i am working in vscode, have a folder env with all the site packages.
in a different folder, I have 3 scripts: init.py, A.py, B.py.

The program runs on init.py.

I used pyinstaller on init.py

```
 pyinstaller init.py --onefile
```

when i click on the executable file in "dist" folder, the init.py works, it pops a UI as expected. When I click on "run", which suppose to do some sort of calculations in a folder, it shows this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
  File "init.py", line 44, in run_main_script
  File "subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'
```

Not sure how to fix this problem. I am using MacOS. Any help is appreciated!

the scripts I have are shown below:

```
# the __init__.py file creates a simple Tkinter GUI with a label and a button. 
# When the user clicks the "Run Main Script" button, it calls the run_main_script() function, which uses subprocess.Popen to run the main script your_script.py as a separate process.

import tkinter as tk # GUI library
from tkinter import messagebox
import os, sys
import subprocess


class Run_assay(tk.Frame):

    master = None

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # check text file
        file_path = 'processed_files.txt'
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'w'):
                pass
        else:
            pass
        
        # define basic UI
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x300')
        self.master.title('HP assay calculator')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Click run button to calculate",font=("Helvetica", 16))
        # span row and column position. pads = addng extra spaces around widget
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.start()
        self.quit()
    
    def run_main_script(self):

        #define main script path, which is the same location as this script
        main_script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "HP_assay_processing.py")
        #print(main_script_path)

        # run main script as a separate process
        subprocess.Popen(["python", main_script_path])

    def run_button(self, main_script):
        self.main_script = main_script
        self.run_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Run", font=("Helvetica", 16), command = self.main_script)
        # run_button.pack(pady=20)
        self.run_button.grid(row=50, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)

    def quit_button(self):
        # stop button
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Quit", font=("Helvetica", 16), command=self.master.destroy)
        self.stop_button.grid(row=50, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)

    def start(self):
        script = self.run_main_script
        self.run_button(script)

    def quit(self):
        self.quit_button()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Run_assay(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

A.py

```
# convert matrix (96 well plate format) into dataframe
import pandas as pd
import os
from calculation import hydroxyproline_assay_calc
import os, sys
import warnings
import mmap
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# for executable purposes, defining a dynamic base path is needed for executing at different locations
# for relative path, this is a folder created in the same directory as the executable for storing HP_assay experiments
def resource_path():
    relative_path='HP_assay'
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    path = os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

    return path
    

def processing(root_directory):
    
    # Loop through file in directory 
    for folder_name in os.listdir(root_directory):
        folder_path = os.path.join(root_directory, folder_name)
        # check if subfolder
        if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
            # print(f"Folder: {folder_name}")
            print(folder_path)
            # # Print the file names in the current subfolder
            # for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
            #     print(f" - {file_name}")

            # have a text file to indicate which folder has been processed
            remembered_folders_file = 'processed_files.txt'
            with open(remembered_folders_file, 'r+') as f:
                if folder_path not in f.read():
                    f.write(folder_path + ',')     
                    pass
                else:
                    continue

            try:
            # # Print the file names in the current subfolder
            # for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
            #     print(f" - {file_name}")

                sample_layout = pd.read_excel(folder_path+'/' + 'sample_layout.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',sheet_name=None, skiprows=0) #skip the first row which is the indexes of the well
                measurements = pd.read_excel(folder_path+'/' + 'abs_reading.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',sheet_name=None, skiprows=0) #skip the first row which is the indexes of the well

            except:
                continue
            
            # ------------------- format sample layout ----------------------------
            combined_layout = pd.DataFrame()
            layout_df_list = []
            for sheet_name in sample_layout:
                if sheet_name != 'Samples':
                    # Column names
                    column_names = ['ID', 'experiment_ID', 'sample_ID','sample_type','pilot_batch','tissue','hide_ID','hide_replicate',
                                    'avg loaded weight mg','avg empty weight mg','net weight mg','operator', 'ug/well', 'media_type', 'scaffold_type', 'date']
                    
                    # drop the rows/columns and expand into appropriate dataframe
                    df = sample_layout[sheet_name].iloc[0:,1:].reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
                    df = df.melt()['value'].str.split(',',expand=True)

                    # combine dataframes into single dataframe
                    combined_layout = combined_layout.append(df)

                    # put dataframes into a list
                    layout_df_list.append(df)

                    # combine dataframes with single row of header
                    layout_df = pd.concat(layout_df_list, ignore_index=True)[combined_layout.columns]
            
            # replace header
            for i, col_name in enumerate(layout_df.columns):
                layout_df.rename(columns = {col_name: column_names[i]}, inplace = True)

            # add constants to table
            layout_df['homogenate volume ul'] = 500
            layout_df['homogenate sample volume ul'] = 100
            layout_df['digest volume ul'] = 1000
            layout_df['digest sample volume ul'] = 20
            
            #  # ------------------- format absorbance measurement layout ----------------------------
            # empty dataframe for combining multiple sheets together    
            combined_abs = pd.DataFrame()
            abs_df_list = []

            # loop through each sheet in excel file
            for sheet_name in measurements:
                if sheet_name != 'General':
                    #df = measurements[sheet_name].iloc[:,1:]
                    df = measurements[sheet_name].iloc[0:,1:]
                    df = df.values
                    row = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H']
                    column = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']

                    # Convert matrices into DataFrames with row and column names
                    df_converted = pd.DataFrame(df, index=row, columns=column)

                    # stack or melt dataframe
                    #df_converted = pd.DataFrame(df, index=row, columns=column).stack().reset_index(name='abs').rename(columns={'level_0':'row','level_1':'column'})
                    df_converted = df_converted.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='column_name', value_name='abs')

                    # Add sheet_name column to each DataFrame
                    df_converted['sheet_name'] = sheet_name
                    combined_abs = combined_abs.append(df_converted)

                    # put dataframes into a list
                    abs_df_list.append(df_converted)

            # combine multiple dataframe and use single list of column names
            combined_abs_df = pd.concat(abs_df_list, ignore_index=True)[df_converted.columns]
            
            # combined = combined.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
            combined_abs_df['location'] = combined_abs_df['index'] + combined_abs_df['column_name']
            combined_abs_df = combined_abs_df.iloc[:,2:]
            
            # join layout and abs measurements together
            final_layout = pd.concat([layout_df, combined_abs_df], axis=1)
            #final_layout.to_csv('data.csv')

            # run calculation
            standard, samples, biopsy_results = hydroxyproline_assay_calc(final_layout)
            print(biopsy_results)
        

            # save the standard and samples only dataframes to csv to respective folder
            #combined.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + 'test.csv')
            samples.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + 'sample.csv')
            standard.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + 'standard.csv')
            biopsy_results.to_csv(folder_path + '/' + 'biopsy_result.csv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # define the path to HP_assay folder
    folder_path = resource_path()

    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        pass
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error','create folder called HP_assay first and then create subfolders for each experiment')
        time.sleep(1)
    # show message box after finished executing
    processing(folder_path)
    time.sleep(3)
    messagebox.showinfo('info','calculation executed, look for files inside HP_assay folder')
```

B.py

```
# analysis for each run
# make sure data table has correct label samples: standard, blank, sample, empty

import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import sklearn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import os

def hydroxyproline_assay_calc(df):

    # normalize reading
    blank_abs = df[df['sample_type'] == 'blank']['abs'].mean()
    df['normalized_abs'] = df['abs'] - blank_abs

    # tables of standards only (raw data)
    standard = df[df['sample_type'] == 'standard']

    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(standard[['normalized_abs']], standard[['ug/well']])
    r_squared = model.score(standard[['normalized_abs']], standard[['ug/well']])
    slope = np.asscalar(np.array(model.coef_))
    intercept = np.asscalar(np.array(model.intercept_))
    #print(slope, intercept, r_squared)

    # populate r_squared value in table of standards
    standard['r_squared'] = r_squared
    standard = standard.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

    # plot scatter vs predicted
    #print(standard[['normalized_abs']], standard[['ug/well']])
    #plt.scatter(standard[['normalized_abs']], standard[['ug/well']], color='g')
    # plt.plot(standard[['normalized_abs']], model.predict(standard[['normalized_abs']]),color='k')
    # plt.show()


    # table of samples only (raw data)
    samples = df[df['sample_type'] == 'sample']

    # calculate 
    samples['ug/well']= samples['normalized_abs']*slope+intercept
    samples['mg/biopsy'] = samples['ug/well']/1000*(samples['homogenate volume ul']/samples['homogenate sample volume ul'])*(samples['digest volume ul']/samples['digest sample volume ul'])

    # average results per hide_ID replicates (each hide_ID has 4 rep)
    average_per_sample = samples.groupby(['experiment_ID','hide_ID', 'hide_replicate','scaffold_type'], squeeze=True).apply(lambda x: ((x['mg/biopsy'].sum()- x['mg/biopsy'].max()-x['mg/biopsy'].min())/2)).reset_index(name='mg/biopsy')
    #print(average_per_sample)

    # average mg/biopsy of the same sample_IDs, and standard dev
    biopsy_mean = average_per_sample.groupby(['experiment_ID','hide_ID','scaffold_type'], squeeze = True).apply(lambda x: x['mg/biopsy'].mean()).reset_index(name='mg/biopsy mean')
    biopsy_std = average_per_sample.groupby(['experiment_ID','hide_ID','scaffold_type'], squeeze = True).apply(lambda x: x['mg/biopsy'].std()).reset_index(name='mg/biopsy std')
    
    # convert to numeric before averaging. because sometimes it has type error
    x = pd.to_numeric(samples['net weight mg'])
    samples['x'] = x
    biopsy_weight = samples.groupby(['hide_ID','scaffold_type'], squeeze = True).apply(lambda x: x['x'].mean()).reset_index(name='net weight mg')
    
    # add to biopsy_mean dataframe
    biopsy_mean['mg/biopsy std'] = biopsy_std['mg/biopsy std']
    biopsy_mean['net weight mg'] = biopsy_weight['net weight mg']
    
    # define scaffold weight base on their type
    biopsy_mean.loc[biopsy_mean['scaffold_type'] == 'V2P1', 'scaffold weight mg'] = 5.75
    biopsy_mean.loc[biopsy_mean['scaffold_type'] == 'PLA', 'scaffold weight mg'] = 4.6
    
    # define average % hydroxyproline in collagens
    biopsy_mean['% hydroxyproline_in_collagen'] = 10.5
    biopsy_mean['% percent_collagen'] = (biopsy_mean['mg/biopsy mean']/(biopsy_mean['% hydroxyproline_in_collagen']/100))/(biopsy_mean['net weight mg']-biopsy_mean['scaffold weight mg'])*100
    #print(biopsy_mean)

    # plt.bar(biopsy_mean['hide_ID'],biopsy_mean['mg/biopsy mean'])
    # plt.errorbar(biopsy_mean['hide_ID'], biopsy_mean['mg/biopsy mean'], yerr=biopsy_mean['mg/biopsy std'], fmt='o', color ='r')
    # plt.show()
#print(average_abs_per_sample)
    
    return standard, samples, biopsy_mean

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('test_HP_calc.csv')
    standard, samples, biopsy_results = hydroxyproline_assay_calc(df)
#print(average_per_sample)

    # save CSV for standard, sample, and average result tables
    # standard.to_csv('standard'+f'{count}.csv')
    # samples.to_csv('samples'+f'{count}.csv')
    # average_abs_per_sample.to_csv('average_abs_reading'+f'{count}.csv')

    # upload to opvia and insert into DB (insert whole file or use API)
```

Comment: The command `python` was not found on your PATH for the current environment.

Comment: Use `sys.executable` to use the embedded Python instead.

Comment: thanks for the comments! I understand python is not found now. Where would i use sys.executable? is it in the subprocess.Popen()?

Comment: You need to import `sys` module and replace `"python"` by `sys.executable` in `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

Comment: thank you it worked! it stopped giving me the python error. However, whenever i click on the "run" button on the GUI, instead of calculating, it just pops up another GUI window. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?